# Multiple parameters in Authorization header not working with Basic Auth

Tags: php, rest, api, http, http-headers

I am creating a basic API using Basic Auth over SSL. The API will be used in a mobile application and allow the creation of an account, with other fairly basic features.

I have decided to hard-code a API key into the mobile application to pass to the API to make it a bit harder for a hacker to access parts of the API that don't require a login (basic auth). Based on what I've read, the API key should be stored in the Authorization header in the HTTP request.

Authorization header:

```
Key ~@3o42jf!34vm3.!
```

My PHP API then readers the header and ensures that the key is correct. If it is, basic elements of the API are available.

The problem comes when trying to perform a task that requires a login to be passed to the API. My Authorization header then looks like this:

```
Key ~@3o42jf!34vm3.! Basic c3RhY2tAZ21haWwuY29tOnRlc3RpbmcxMjM=
```

The API can still read the key, but the email/password string that I access with `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` are now not set. Is the only way to get around this to read the header manually through `apache_request_headers()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a custom header, you should use a separate identifier for it. For example:

```
X-Api-Key: ~@3o42jf!34vm3.!
```

And then you can leave the basic auth header as it is (since it indeed won't work if you insert custom data in it).

On the PHP side, your custom header can be accessed with `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_KEY']`

Also make sure that your request headers are in the correct format. It should be like this:

```
GET /api/v1/tickets HTTP/1.1
Host: 123.123.123.123
Authorization: Basic c3RhY2tAZ21haWwuY29tOnzzz3RpbmcxMjM=
X-Api-Key: z7='sL(=}24qv'3F
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e657c66f-2db1-bf76-78c5-777305b5bfe6
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Will accept as soon as timer is up. I was just about to ask how to access the API key in PHP and then you edited! :-)

Comment: Strange - `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_KEY'])` is returning false despite adding `X-Api-Key` in the header. Any ideas why? I've tried it with a colon and without (not sure which is correct - but made no difference).

Comment: if you do a `var_dump($_SERVER)`, do you have any `HTTP_...` keys in there?

Comment: Yes but just the typical ones, none relating to the API key. (By typical I mean host, connection, cache control etc)

Comment: Hmm, then I guess on the client side, you're not sending the right headers. Note that it should be exactly `X-Api-Key: ~@3o42jf!34vm3.!` with a colon after X-Api-Key. Do you have ways to see the request you're sending?

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the raw request: http://pastebin.com/h0Yycha2 Oh gee this should be fun I forgot to change the IP

Comment: I've updated my answer - the problem is that the api key and basic auth are in the same header. They should be under two separate keys.

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for the misunderstanding! :-)